# CoreData Int32 Scalar Issue

Tags: swift, core-data

I am fairly new with working in CoreData at this point. 
I am trying to add a level to a character. I have the Entity of Character, and an added Attribute of Level. For the level, I set it to type Integer 32 and use Scalar types. The following image is how I have level setup:

[image] 
In my core data file for Character, I have the value setup like the following:

```
@objc(Character)
class Character: WHNSManagedObject {
    
    @NSManaged var level: Int
}
```

When I run the app and access the level value, I am getting an [error] warning in the console output: 
[18498:840353] [error] warning: Property 'level' is a 64 bit scalar type on class 'Character' that does not match its entity's property's 32 bit scalar type.  Implicit coercion to 32 bits in the database is not recommended.

So my question is really just what am I doing wrong here? I am confused why I the Int32 is not able to scale to Int64 when using Int in the core data file I made. 
I am trying to keep the types scaled lower so they don't use up unnecessary space. And I would also like to be able to define the value as Int, so I don't have to typecast every time I am accessing the variable.

Thank you in advance for any help, tips, or advice you are able to give!

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined your `@Managed` property to be the same type as the entity attribute. What you can do to work with `Int` is to wrap it in another property

```
public var levelValue: Int {
    get {
        Int(level)
    }
    set {
        Int16(exactly: newValue) ?? 0
    }
}
```

You could even make `level` private if you want to avoid any direct access to it from outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric types in Core Data need to use properties with the same type. The type must be exact; you can't have an integer of one size in the model editor and a different size in code.

Since your attribute is "Integer 32" in the model editor, the Swift property must be an `Int32`. You're using `Int` which is 64 bits. Swift doesn't automatically convert between them. You need to make `level` an `Int32`. If you need `Int` in code, add other code to convert between `Int` and `Int32`.